# Shocked by the strange behavior of unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++14, unordered-map, c++17

It is a very simple piece of code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {  
    std::unordered_map<int, int> m;
    m[1] = m.find(1) == m.end() ? 0 : 1;
    printf("%d\n", m[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

If the map does not contain `1`, then assign `m[1]=0`; otherwise `m[1]=1`. I tried this with different `gcc` compilers [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find).

gcc5.2 always outputs 1, gcc7.1 always outputs 0.

Why is it so different? Shouldn't it be 0 always? I cannot understand this behavior. What is the safest way to write such logic?

Comment: Good example for _undefined behavior_?? _"What is the safest way to write such logic?"_ Not to do it.

Comment: I didn't know this behavior is **undefined**. Complier should warn me this. Wasted much time on this!

Comment: So everybody should read the complete C++ standard before programming.

Comment: @LaoMao No, you should write programs that are undeniably understandable.

Comment: Suggestion: change the title to something more general like: "Does assignment sequenced order is undefined behavior ?"

Comment: In C++ the default rule of a all functions and operators is that "argument evaluation is not ordered".  It occurs before the function call/operator itself.  C++17 added *some* restrictions.  Do not modify a value as you are reading it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The result is dependent on whether the compiler supports C++ 2017 or not.

According to the C++ 2017 Standard (5.18 Assignment and compound assignment operators)

> 1 The assignment operator (=) and the compound assignment operators
>   all group right-to-left. All require a modifiable lvalue as their left
>   operand and return an lvalue referring to the left operand. The result
>   in all cases is a bit-field if the left operand is a bit-field. In all
>   cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value computation of the
>   right and left operands, and before the value computation of the
>   assignment expression **The right operand is sequenced before the left
>   operand.**. With respect to an indeterminately-sequenced function call, the 
>   operation of a compound assignment is a single evaluation

On the other hand according to the C++ 2014 Standard (5.18 Assignment and compound assignment operators)

> 1 The assignment operator (=) and the compound assignment operators
>   all group right-to-left. All require a modifiable lvalue as their left
>   operand and return an lvalue referring to the left operand. The result
>   in all cases is a bit-field if the left operand is a bit-field. In all
>   cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value computation of the
>   right and left operands, and before the value computation of the
>   assignment expression. With respect to an indeterminately-sequenced
>   function call, the operation of a compound assignment is a single
>   evaluation.

As you can see the statement in bold is absent in the quote from the C++ 2014 Standard.

So you should not rely on the order of the evaluation of the left and the right operands.

Comment: Does this imply something like `x = x < 0 ? 0 : x` or `y = y > 100 ? 1 : 0` are UB too before C++17?

Comment: Why would they be UB? What side effects the RHS has, that had a sequencing dependency on the LHS?

Comment: @taskinoor no because it doesn't matter which order you evaluate the left and right side.   And the actual assignment is always after both sides are evaluated.  The issue in the original question is that calling operator[] on a map CREATES the entry with the default value if it didn't previously exist, which changes the result of the find() call on the right.

Comment: @xaxxon thanks for pointing to the difference caused by `operator[]` of map.